# PostgreSQL sending large XML values is too slow

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

We have a table with around 10k rows, with the following scheme:

1. item_id: TEXT (Primary Key)
2. xml_1: XML
3. xml_2: XML
4. country: TEXT

Running the following query takes around 9 to 10 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM info_table
WHERE item_id IN ('item1','item2','...' -> 'item2000')
```

Each of our SELECT query is composed of an array of around 2,000+- of items ids (Strings), the query is extremely simple and we are looking to optimize it (if possible).
**The size of the XML of each row is around 100Kb**

If it helps our query is being done in Node.JS using Knex, such as:

```
client.select('*').from('info_table').where('item_id','in',ids)
```

The server is using **PostgreSQL 14** hosted by GCP Cloud SQL with 2vCPU, 8GB Memory and 100GB SSD

Results of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
Seq Scan on epg_test  (cost=4.85..740.17 rows=1939 width=601) (actual time=0.168..3.432 rows=1837 loops=1)
  Filter: (epg_id = ANY (Array of 2000 IDs)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 6051
  Buffers: shared hit=617
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=130
Planning Time: 1.999 ms
Execution Time: 3.590 ms
```

Any ideas of what we can do?

Comment: Put your ID values in a temp table and join to it. A primary key value as text is also not going to be performant, a primary key should be as narrow as possible.

Comment: It sounds like your SELECT operation retrieves 2000 x 100Kib = 200MiB of result set data. That's a big SQL result set. There's no weird SQL voodoo index magic that makes handling that much data super fast.

Comment: @O.Jones We are aware that the size is quite big, that's exactly why I included it in bold, we are trying to optimize it as much as possible, which is the purpose of this question.

Comment: @Stu Making the primary key as varchar(255) made the query slower at around 13 seconds, would you care to give an example as to how to join the values into a temp table?

Comment: See [Slow query questions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions) for the information that is needed to answer this. Add missing information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have added the results of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) to the question, the rest are irrelevant as it's a GCP Cloud SQL instance

Comment: 1) FYI, folks generally prefer the `TEXT` format for the `EXPLAIN` output. 2) The query is only taking `Execution Time: 3.590 ms`. You will need to define how you are arriving at *... 9 to 10 seconds...*?  Best guess is network lag and/or display lag.

Comment: It has to be serialization / network / deserialization / display time. For what it's worth 20MiB / second == 160mbps  is respectable throughput. To get it faster you'll need to colocate the dbms and the client machine, and make sure you have at least gigabit ethernet connecting them. Again, very little magic.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, what about compressing the XML (using GZIP?) and storing it as compressed data in the SQL?

Comment: 1) Do you need to load all 2000 items at once? 2) Does Knex support server side cursors?

Comment: You need to paginate large query results if they are rendered in a row by row basis on the front-end, check https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/. Or if it's used for aggregation do the processing on the db server side.

Comment: I need all the rows at once as these rows will be combined into 1 XML file that will be served to the user

Comment: @ia244 then probably is a server side job.

Comment: @PepeNO That another way that we are exploring, our goal is to make our infrastructure serverless as possible using GCP

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Btw that *was* the `TEXT` format of `EXPLAIN`, just mangled into an array of row object by their db library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comments, it's clear that the PostgreSQL complexity of your query is minimal. It takes under 4ms. Therefore, indexing or other SQL tuning isn't part of your solution.

It's also clear that you're returning a large result set, amounting to something like 0.2GiB. And, you're doing it in ten seconds or so. That means your throughput is 20MiB/sec which is excellent. This is especially true if you're retrieving it into a machine on your premises from a server located somewhere in GCP. (Keep in mind that 20megaBYTES a second takes upwards of 160megaBITS per second. That's a significant amount of bandwidth to push from one machine to another.)

How can you get this big data transfer to complete faster?

1. More bandwidth. That you have to take up with your operations people. Or by moving the machine running the query closer on the net to the database machine.
2. Compressing the data in transit. XML is generally quite compressible (information-theoretically it's almost pathologically verbose). The PostgreSQL driver for nodejs (and knex) has a deprecated [sslcompression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLCOMPRESSION) connection-string flag that will apply lossless compression to the client-server network traffic. That might help.

   Or, you may be able to tunnel your database connection through an ssh session set up with the -C -- compressed protocol -- flag.
3. Compressing the data at rest in your database. If you do this make sure you store the compressed xml in columns with a binary data type.

All that being said, ten seconds to process that much data doesn't seem terribly unreasonable.

Comment: Compressing the XML to GZIP and storing the binary data reduced the query to 2 seconds, thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the input, it was very helpful.

We managed to get the query down to 2 seconds by compressing the XML data before inserting to our PostgreSQL resulting in a massive reduction in size generally.

We compressed the XML using "zlib" and GZIP.

Comment: Hi, this is not an answer, it's a comment. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)